# How to handle async concurrent requests correctly?

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency, sails.js

Let's say I have some sort of game. I have a buyItem function like this:

```
buyItem: function (req, res) {
    // query the users balance
    // deduct user balance
    // buy the item
}
```

If I spam that route until the user balance is deducted (the 2nd query) the user's balance is still positive.

What I have tried:

```
buyItem: function (req, res) {
    if(req.session.user.busy) return false;
    req.session.user.busy = true;
    // query the users balance
    // deduct user balance
    // buy the item
}
```

The problem is `req.session.user.busy` will be `undefined` for the first ~5 requests. So that doesn't work either.

How do we handle such situations? I'm using the Sails.JS framework if that is important.

Comment: Can't you just call `.update()` on the model and skip the query for the balance?

Comment: You gave me an idea. You mean setting balance must be positive in the database and then running the `update` query, right? If it was successful (so the balance is still positive) we can credit the item?

Comment: Yeah, just set the update conditions such that it's restricted to that user with a balance greater than or equal to the item's price. If the query was successful, then add the item to their list/inventory/whatever.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ## Update 2
>
> Sails 1.0 now has full [transaction support](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/waterline/datastores/transaction.md), via the [`.getDatastore()`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/waterline/models/getDatastore.md) method.  Example:

```
// Get a reference to the default datastore, and start a transaction.
await sails.getDatastore().transaction(async (db, proceed)=> {
  // Now that we have a connection instance in `db`, pass it to Waterline
  // methods using `.usingConnection()` to make them part of the transaction:
  await BankAccount.update({ balance: 5000 }).usingConnection(db);
  // If an error is thrown, the transaction will be rolled back.
  // Or, you can catch errors yourself and call `proceed(err)`.
  // To commit the transaction, call `proceed()`
  return proceed();
  // You can also return a result with `proceed(null, result)`.
});
```

> ## Update
>
> As several commenters have noted, the code below doesn't work when [connection pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) is enabled.  At the time that this was originally posted, not all of the adapters pooled by default, but at this point it should be assumed that they do, so that each individual method call (`.query()`, `.findOne()`, etc.) could be on a different connection, and operating outside of the transaction.  The next major version of Waterline will have transaction support, but until then, the only way to ensure that your queries are transactional is to use the raw database driver package (e.g. [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) or [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)).

It sounds like what you need is a [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).  Sails doesn't support transactions at the framework level yet (it's on the roadmap) but if you're using a database that supports them (like Postgres or MySQL), you can use the `.query()` method of your model to access the underlying adapter and run [native commands](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Transactions).  Here's an example:

```
buyItem: function(req, res) {
  try {
    // Start the transaction
    User.query("BEGIN", function(err) {
      if (err) {throw new Error(err);}
      // Find the user
      User.findOne(req.param("userId").exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {throw new Error(err);}
        // Update the user balance
        user.balance = user.balance - req.param("itemCost");
        // Save the user
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {throw new Error(err);}
          // Commit the transaction
          User.query("COMMIT", function(err) {
            if (err) {throw new Error(err);}
            // Display the updated user
            res.json(user);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  } 
  // If there are any problems, roll back the transaction
  catch(e) {
    User.query("ROLLBACK", function(err) {
      // The rollback failed--Catastrophic error!
      if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
      // Return the error that resulted in the rollback
      return res.serverError(e);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. This is actually very helpful. Seems not too hard to implement. I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @sgress454 does this work when using connection pooling? (which I believe is enabled by default)

Comment: @chadMcElligott has a good point. If connection pooling is enabled, then it is not assured that you get the same connection in each User.query call. which is important if you want transactions to work properly

Comment: @ChadMcElligott, RussellSantos Yup, y'all are completely right.  At the time I wrote this the adapters didn't all pool by default.  Updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @sgress454 to be clear, has the code snippet been updated or has just a warning been added? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to grab a connection from the waterline pool and use that single connection for the duration of the transaction?

Comment: Would this example also work, when after(in its callback) User.findOne() we try to Update another Model? So this Transaction (from BEGIN till COMMIT) is blocking also over multiple Models?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out. But as long as your not using multiple instances or clusters, you *should* just be able to store the status in memory. Because node is single threaded there shouldn't be any problems with atomicity.

```
var inProgress = {};

function buyItem(req, res) {
    if (inProgress[req.session.user.id]) {
        // send error response
        return;
    }

    inProgress[req.session.user.id] = true;

    // or whatever the function is..
    req.session.user.subtractBalance(10.00, function(err, success) {
        delete inProgress[req.session.user.id];

        // send success response
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When you do a loop in the Client (5 HTTP requests) the first one gets immidiately a response the rest waits for some seconds and get also true and you got 5 times substract balance... not working like this.