# sailsjs framework doesn't support transaction

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline, node-mysql

The `sails.js` framework doesn't support transaction. In the GitHub issues, they talk about `transaction()`. But it's not suitable to code multiple queries in a transaction.

So I think one solution that use node-mysql module.
But I think that if I create new connection to MySQL and use still sails.js framework connecting to database by waterline, the performance could be diminished.

Is it true?

Comment: Check if https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mysql-transactions helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to open a separate `sails-mysql` connection.  You can use [the `query` method of the adapter](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/query.html) to gain access to the underlying MySQL node driver and perform arbitrary queries, including transactions.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100188/345484) for an example.